# How to create board NxN using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create board game (like chess board game) with JavaScript.

When I tried to do it this is what happened:
[image]

The `<tr>` got closed immediately with `</tr>`, same thing with `<table> </table>`
I tried to replace the `append()` method with `appendTo()` or `add()` but it didn't help

This is my **JavaScript** code:

```
var boardSize = 5;

$(function() { //on load
    printBoard(boardSize);
});

function printBoard(i_BoardSize) {
    var maxRow = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
    var maxCol = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
    var num = 1;

    $("#board").append("<table oncontextmenu=\"return false\">");
    for(var row = maxRow - 1; row >= 0 ; row--) { 
           $("#board").append("<tr>");
            for(var col = 0; col < maxCol ; col++) {
                $("#board").append("<td>" + num + "</td>");
                num++;
            }

            $("#board").append("</tr>");
       }
        $("#board").append("</table>");
}
```

**CSS:**

```
td {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

.redborder {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.blueborder {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/board.css' />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/board.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> <center><h3><font size="20" color="black"> Board Game</font></h3></center></p>
        <div>
            <div id="board">
                <div class="cell">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.append` appends "whole" DOM elements. You can first generate the HTML and then `.append` it. See also http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements

Comment: `<center>` and `<font>` tags seem to be the longest-standing deprecated tags in HTML history.
You're using a stylesheet, please try to include formatting logic there, not via deprecated tags. Also, your structure is wrong, a `<h3>` must not be enclosed by `<p>` tags.

Comment: It is documented here [`http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2).

Comment: You know, a subtle side note being that you can just append 25 divs each having a 20% width, floating and it would also make a board without having to use tables, which should probably remain reserved for tabular data only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because jQuery [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method not supporting only closing tags and trying to close tags if they wasn't closed in provided param. To solve this you need to assign your `append()` result to some variable, for example:

```
var myTable = $("<table oncontextmenu=\"return false\"></table>").appendTo("#board");
```

and then append your rows to this var:

```
var myRow = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo( myTable );
```

Same with columns:

```
myRow.append("<td>" + num + "</td>");
```

By using [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method you will be able to get newly created elements.

So your final code should look like:

```
var boardSize = 5;

$(function() { //on load
    printBoard(boardSize);
});

function printBoard(i_BoardSize) {
    var maxRow = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
    var maxCol = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
    var num = 1;

    var myTable = $("<table oncontextmenu=\"return false\"></table>").appendTo("#board");
    for (var row = maxRow - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        var myRow = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(myTable);
        for (var col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
            myRow.append("<td>" + num + "</td>");
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot '$' after "var myRow = " but it works after adding the '$' :)

Answer (score 1):

The others have supplied you with why this is happening but I thought I might give an example of how you might make better use of css and more recent dom usage.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/np62shu6/1/

But the basic idea is to define the number of cells, then write out a series of divs that have a 20% float value. In the end you have a chess board with a cell data attribute.

HTML:

```
<div id="game">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cell{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

.odd{
 background:#eee;   
}
```

JS (assumed you place this in a load handler):

```
var cells = 25;
var cell;
var h;

for(var i = 1; i <= cells; i ++)
{
    cell = $('<div>').addClass('cell').attr('data-cell', i).text(i);
    if(i % 2 == 1)
        cell.addClass('odd');

    $('#game').append(cell);
}

h = $('.cell:last-of-type').width();
$('.cell').css({height: h, lineHeight: h + 'px'});
```

As others have said, append is a sequential method, so calling it one after the other will just keep dropping things in the DOM. But you can create elements, then add things to those elements using append, then use append to add that whole group to another...

My example does not show this. My example is just an alternative to what you wrote. I would not do it the way you are doing it is all.

Another slight side note - chess boards have 64 cells (8 x 8), but I left it at 25 because your example did this.

Answer (score 0):

When you append a tag with jQuery it doesn't work like appending text to a HTML string. Instead it creates the dom element. Try something like this instead, notice the absence of closing tags and td is appended directly to the latest tr:

```
var boardSize = 5;

$(function() { //on load
    printBoard(boardSize);
});

function printBoard(i_BoardSize)
{
    var maxRow = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
    var maxCol = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
    var num = 1;

    $("#board").append("<table oncontextmenu=\"return false\">");
    for(var row = maxRow - 1; row >= 0 ; row--)
       { 
           $("#board table").append("<tr>");
            for(var col = 0; col < maxCol ; col++)
             {
                 $("#board tr:last").append("<td>" + num + "</td>");
                num++;
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() { //on load
    var boardSize = 5;
    printBoard(boardSize);
});
function printBoard(i_BoardSize)
{
  var maxRow = parseInt(i_BoardSize),
      maxCol = maxRow;

  var $table = $("<table oncontextmenu='return false'></table>").appendTo($("#board"));
  for(var row = 1; row <= maxRow; row++)
  { 
    var $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($table);
    for(var col = 1; col <= maxCol; col++)
      {
        $row.append("<td>" + (row*col) + "</td>");
      }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

.redborder {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.blueborder {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> <center><h3><font size="20" color="black"> Board Game</font></h3></center></p>
<div>
    <div id="board">
        <div class="cell">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Side note: You don't have to append the closing tags manually...*

Comment: Why? I expect better answers from a 10k user :-/

Comment: @FelixKling the Fastest Gun in the West Problem... i posted something that works which came to my mind, then thought of improving it later. Then i had issues with my internet connection and ... well i'm pretty sure you haven't experienced having to share a 1Mbps wifi with 30-40 people who even downloads torrents with whatever bits they're getting... :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
function printBoard(i_BoardSize)
{
var maxRow = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
var maxCol = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
var num = 1;

$("#board").append("<table oncontextmenu=\"return false\">");
for(var row = maxRow - 1; row >= 0 ; row--)
   {
      #here 
       $("#board").append("<tr>");
        for(var col = 0; col < maxCol ; col++)
         {
             #here
             $("#board").append("<td>" + num + "</td>");
            num++;
        }

        $("#board").append("</tr>");
   }
    $("#board").append("</table>");
}
```

You are appending each element to the `#board` instead of properly nesting them. try keeping the created elements in variables, and do nesting:

```
function printBoard(i_BoardSize)
{
var maxRow = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
var maxCol = parseInt(i_BoardSize);
var num = 1;

$tableelement = $("<table oncontextmenu=\"return false\"></table>");
$("#board").append($tableelement);
for(var row = maxRow - 1; row >= 0 ; row--)
   {
      #here 
       $rowelement = $("<tr></tr>");
       $tableelement.append($rowelement);
        for(var col = 0; col < maxCol ; col++)
         {
             #here
             $rowelement.append("<td>" + num + "</td>");
            num++;
        }
   }
}
```

Reason: certain browsers will immediately try to fix malformed HTML, and in the middle of the execution, the items are malformed while you insert it, and are wellformed after you finish. in the middle -this function's execution is not atomic- the code is malformed and the browser tries to fix it by closing the tags you add. That's why you need to add elements by nesting -opening and closing the tags for them beforehand-

Answer (score 0):

This is way easier and cleaner if you just learn JavaScript and work in the DOM.

```
function makeBoardWithoutJQuery(xs, ys) {

    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    for (var y=0; y<ys; ++y) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var x=0; x<xs; ++x) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = (y*xs) + x;
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }

    table.appendChild(tbody);
    return table;
}
```